# Prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ax^2+b}}$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ax^2+b}}$ is uniformly continuous for $a,b>0$.

Choose $\epsilon >0$. Let $\delta= ?$.
Choose $x,y \in R$.
Assume $|x-y|< \epsilon$.
Then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|\frac{1}{\sqrt{ax^2+b}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{ay^2+b}}|=|\frac{\sqrt{ay^2+b}-\sqrt{ax^2+b}}{\sqrt{ax^2+b}\sqrt{ay^2+b}}|$.

How to simplify from here?
I know the top, $|{\sqrt{ay^2+b}-\sqrt{ax^2+b}}|\leq\sqrt{a}|x-y|$, but I don't know what to do next? I hope someone can give me some hints on this problem.

Comment: More generally, assume $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}$ exist. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Which are your hypothesis concerning $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I quick way is so to use Mean Value theorem and then show the derivative is uniformly bounded.

Comment: by considering that the denominator stays away from zero by a positive distance, $b$ i guess, it is enough to make the numerator small. And this you have already shown by founding a bound.

Comment: But $|{\sqrt{ay^2+b}-\sqrt{ax^2+b}}|\leq\sqrt{a}|x-y|$ is not quite accurate. $\sqrt{x^2-y^2} \neq x-y$.

Comment: a and b both greater than 0, it requires to use $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ to solve.

Comment: The denominator is at least $b$, so using your inequality, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\sqrt{a}/b |x-y|<\sqrt{a}/b\epsilon$. So you need to choose $\epsilon$ so that $\sqrt{a}/b\epsilon\leq \delta$.

Comment: If $a,b>0$ then state that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with the words after your first "then" :).

From what you gave, if $a \leq 0$ then the proof is trivial; let $a > 0$. Suppose first that $b > 0$. 
Note that $\sqrt{ax^{2}+b}\sqrt{ay^{2}+b} \geq \sqrt{b}\sqrt{b} = b$ for all suitable $x,y$; so if $\psi (x,y,a,b)$ is the last term of the independent line, then
$$
\psi(x,y,a,b) \leq |\frac{1}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{f(y)}|/b \leq \sqrt{a}|x-y|/b
$$
by your result.
Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have
$\sqrt{a}|x-y|/b < \varepsilon$ if $|x-y| < b\varepsilon/\sqrt{a}$; so taking $\delta := b\varepsilon/\sqrt{a}$ suffices.
You must know how to prove for $b \leq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I solved it few minutes ago and got the same result. :)

Comment: Great for you! :D Keep it up